# UCMA Standalone IVR without LYNC server

Tags: ucma

Cannot we use the UCMA for accepting the phone calls (IVR like) and responding to them? I want to connect to the PBX and not the Lync server. Please answer if some one know this or let me know whether you need more info?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can to so that.  I do it to create B2BUA call's between Lync and our own SipServer.

Check out this blog [article](http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/09/30/standalone-ucma-application/) on that very subject.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have the same code. I have the SIP server ip, phone number, username and password. But I don't know how to make the code to listen to the phone number. I could not find any sample of doing that in the internet. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense if you understand SIP.  It's not a function UCMA or sip.  You setup a sip endpoint.  That endpoint has a "user" part.  That is how some other endpoint communicates with you.  That "user" part could be a "number" (e.g. phone number).  Normal likely it's just a "user" e.g. symbolic number like "1000".  The "listening" for a "number" is not the responsibility of the sip endpoint.  It's normally a setup of the PBX itself.  You will have some sort of PSTN gateway setup for the PBX with mappings from DDI to sip user.  It's a PBX setup not a sip endpoint setup.

Comment: The setup of PSTN gateway DDI mappings is very specific to the PBX type.  So there is no generic answer on how to do it.

Comment: Using the information (phone extn, server IP, proxy IP, username, password) I am able to connect and get calls via XLite softphone. However I am trying with the same information using the code at [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/28cbf95f-3df0-450b-b51c-cfc8e55faa58/ucma-sipendpoint-without-lync?forum=ucmanagedsdk). I could NOT register and get the calls to my IVR application. I am getting the exception at lines.[code] (catch (AuthenticationException ae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Registration ax");
        isEndPointRegistered = false;
    })

Comment: Need a lot more information to determine what the problem is.  Most likely the sip log to determine why the registration is failing.  It could be a number of things, UCMA may not support the auth options that the PBX server uses.  Your username may not be valid for that PBX server.